# JavaScript how to get if a button is active (after click)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have only one button. In css you can use *button:active { do stuff }* and it will become valid once and after the button is clicked, so interacting with other objects (clicking on a image) will cause
the statement to be null. How Can I translate this into java script?
Something like that:

```
const Ham_Button = document.querySelector('button');

while (Ham_Button.isActive)
{
   do stuff
}
```

I tried this:

```
const Ham_Button = document.querySelector('button');

const ClickEvent = function() {
    Hidden_Nav.style.display = "block";
}

Ham_Button.addEventListener("click", ClickEvent);
```

But the event is triggered only and only when I click, not after, when the element is still the last interacted object.

Comment: `while (Ham_Button.isActive)` would be bad as it would block the page from ever doing anything else

Comment: What's typically done is adding a click listener that runs when anything other than the button is clicked.

Comment: maybe there is a way to detect if any other element is clicked

Comment: Add a click event for those elements? Or add one for the entire page, and then use if statements to decide what to do based on which element is clicked.

Comment: You can try to set focus on button after clicking it: `document.querySelector('button').focus();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `onblur` event. With that you can detect if the user "removes" the active state of a link or button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which element currently has focus by consulting

```js
document.activeElement
```

This has good [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement#browser_compatibility).

Don't put this in a `while` loop as in your example, though, or you'll lock up the browser's thread of execution. If you must check this periodically, consider using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Can an element be active, but not have focus?

Comment: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement defines `activeElement` as the element that currently has focus. It reads like the same thing.

Comment: But is that the same as CSS's active?

Comment: No, you can tab to a button to give it focus, but it only becomes active once you click it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
const Ham_Button = document.querySelector('button');

let hamIsActive = false;

Ham_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(hamIsActive) {
         // do stuff, add styles...
         hamIsActive = false; // to add a toggle functionality
    } else {
         // do stuff, add styles...
         hamIsActive = true; // to add a toggle functionality
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the mousedown event fired once each time the button is pressed.

You also have the mouseup event fired once each time the button is released.

you can't use a while loop since it would block the main thread but you can setup a tick loop (fired roughly every 16ms, or 60 times per second)

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const counterDown = document.getElementById('counter_down');

let totalTimeDown = 0;
let downRequestId;
let lastTimeDown = 0;

function loopDown(time) {
  if (lastTimeDown) {
    const dt = time - lastTimeDown;
    totalTimeDown += dt;
    counterDown.innerHTML = (totalTimeDown / 1000).toFixed(2);
  }
  lastTimeDown = time;
  downRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(loopDown);
}

function onMouseDown() {
  downRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(loopDown);
}

function onMouseUp() {
  lastTimeDown = 0;
  cancelAnimationFrame(downRequestId);
}

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
btn.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

// SAME LOGIC FOR FOCUS/BLUR
const counterFocus = document.getElementById('counter_focus');
let totalTimeFocused = 0;
let focusRequestId;
let lastTimeFocus = 0;

function loopFocus(time) {
  if (lastTimeFocus) {
    const dt = time - lastTimeFocus;
    totalTimeFocused += dt;
    counterFocus.innerHTML = (totalTimeFocused / 1000).toFixed(2);
  }
  lastTimeFocus = time;
  focusRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(loopFocus);
}

function onFocus() {
  focusRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(loopFocus);
}

function onBlur() {
  lastTimeFocus = 0;
  cancelAnimationFrame(focusRequestId);
}

btn.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
btn.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
```

```css
button:focus {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
button:active {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">press me</button>
<div>time pressed: <span id="counter_down">0</span>s</div>
<div>time focused: <span id="counter_focus">0</span>s</div>
```

Note that you can switch for `focus` and `blur` events if that's what you are looking for